# Absolute middle in bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a bootstrap card with a logo in the absolute middle, but the logo is fixed at the top?!? How can I accomplish this?

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card mini-stat">
        <div class="card-body text-center" style="height:10em">
          <img src="public/assets/images/entrylogos/chromebook.png" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS class:

```
.card-img-top {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: No CSS necessary. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#align-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it works with you, I just have to decrease the width of the picture, if you can notice I decreased to it to 50% and it worked with me magically because of the logo I have used, but I think that you should rechoose your width and height, just use what suits your logo.

```
.card-img-top { 
                max-width: 50%;
                max-height: 50%;
                object-fit: contain;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```